# Print one line at a time from text file using python

Tags: python, list

ok so I've poured over this site and I CAN'T find anything that works.
here is my code

```
print("Type the filename")
file_again = raw_input("> ")

lines = [6]
with open(file_again, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

BUT I can't get it to print out line by line and all it would be is one digit in each line. I'd also like to use a counter but I can't get that syntax right. i tried enumerating but that didnt work out well for me

Comment: You're reading in one line `.read()` and then splitting that one line `.splitlines()`. Use `.readlines()`.

Comment: That code does print out line by line. Do you want line numbers on the front? Then try `for num, line in enumerate(lines, 1):`.

Comment: You need to tell us what you want the output to be to get any help. A quick description... an example...

Comment: out put i want this  >                                                                                                        pets    count                                                                                                         with the numbers from txt.pets under pet and under count i want my count

Comment: Can you show us a sample input and output file. It sounds like you want to parse txt.pets and write it out in some planned format but we can't do much without seeing the data. Only a half dozen example lines would do.

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/t4wzuv.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: the only way i got it like this was spaces in my text file so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("Type the filename")
file_again = raw_input("> ")

with open(file_again, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for num, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    print "%s: %s" % (num, line)
```

Basically, you had two issues:

1. You need to loop over the lines. For this, use `readlines()`, which returns all the lines in a list you can iterate through.
2. You need to print a counter and the line value. For this, `enumerate()` will provide you a counter in the `for` loop concisely. Then, format the printed line to show both the counter and the line value.

Comment: Thank you so muuch. thats exacty what i needed. So enumerate does what function exactly.

Comment: it provides a counter in a specified increment, and lets you call the counter directly. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

File objects in Python are iterators. So you can iterate over them directly:

```
from __future__  import print_function # get Python 3 printing in Python 2

with open(file_again) as fobj:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fobj, 1):
          print('{}: {}'.format(lineno, line), end='')
```

The `end=''` does not add a newline to the print because each line has a newline at its end already.

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily work with large files because you don't need to read the whole file at once.